# How to create new order in Kentico from my site?

Tags: kentico

Am totally new to Kentico i created E-commerce site and want to use API to create orders. can any one tell me which method i should use??, also want to ask if any one tried to display kentico website on Sharepoint application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an order is a little more complex as you need to get the Customer, Currency, Shipping address, Product and other possibly related objects. A simple example can look like this:

```
// Gets the first customer whose last name is 'Smith'
CustomerInfo customer = CustomerInfoProvider.GetCustomers()
                                            .WhereEquals("CustomerLastName", "Smith")
                                            .FirstObject;

// Prepares the order addresses
OrderAddressInfo orderBillingAddress = null;
OrderAddressInfo orderShippingAddress = null;

// Gets the customer's address
AddressInfo customerAddress = AddressInfoProvider.GetAddresses()
                                                    .WhereEquals("AddressCustomerID", customer.CustomerID)
                                                    .FirstObject;

if (customerAddress != null)
{
    // Gets the data from the customer's address
    orderBillingAddress = OrderAddressInfoProvider.CreateOrderAddressInfo(customerAddress);
    orderShippingAddress = OrderAddressInfoProvider.CreateOrderAddressInfo(customerAddress);

    // Sets the order addresses
    OrderAddressInfoProvider.SetAddressInfo(orderBillingAddress);
    OrderAddressInfoProvider.SetAddressInfo(orderShippingAddress);
}

// Gets a status for the order
OrderStatusInfo orderStatus = OrderStatusInfoProvider.GetOrderStatusInfo("NewStatus", SiteContext.CurrentSiteName);

// Gets a currency for the order
CurrencyInfo currency = CurrencyInfoProvider.GetCurrencyInfo("NewCurrency", SiteContext.CurrentSiteName);

if ((customer != null) && (orderStatus != null) && (currency != null) && (orderBillingAddress != null))
{
    // Creates a new order object and sets its properties
    OrderInfo newOrder = new OrderInfo
    {
        OrderInvoiceNumber = "1",
        OrderBillingAddress = orderBillingAddress,
        OrderShippingAddress = orderShippingAddress,
        OrderTotalPrice = 200,
        OrderTotalTax = 30,
        OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
        OrderStatusID = orderStatus.StatusID,
        OrderCustomerID = customer.CustomerID,
        OrderSiteID = SiteContext.CurrentSiteID,
        OrderCurrencyID = currency.CurrencyID
    };

    // Saves the order to the database
    OrderInfoProvider.SetOrderInfo(newOrder);
}
```

This was taken from [Kentico docs](https://docs.kentico.com/display/API9/Orders#Orders-Creatinganeworder) which I would really recommend to check out as there are many more examples which you might find useful.

As for your second question - I'm not quite sure what do you mean by displaying Kentico in a Sharepoint application. Kentico is a standalone ASP Web forms application that needs to run on a IIS and cannot by itself be *embedded* in a Sharepoint.

Comment: Very handy thnx alot

Comment: Another question plz .. i can't find in doc. how to get products data from DB so i used to select it by my self using alot of inner joins .. so i just want to ask is their another approach to get product data and it's attachments and options ?? Appreciate your support.

Comment: Hi, I have added answer to your second question so feel free to check it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826799/creating-more-than-one-site-in-kentico/36833719#36833719)